# Resume ways of using dockers (web development)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Screenshot: [my docker-compose for wordpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exKoU.png)

1. I've learned last week how to deploy 3 containers of wordpress, phpmyadmin and mysql. They work fine. The containers were connected between them, using a volume and the same network. The docker was configured from a **docker compose** file. **.yml** I used *Git* of my native operative system to version the changes.
2. But then I found another way to do the same:
   I installed a image of Debian, then added git, apache2, mariadb and phpmyadmin, i connected all and use a **"docker commit"** to save changes of my development every time.
3. Then, a coworker told me to use a **docker-file** and add volumes an use Git for versioning.

Which is the best way?
What problems have the first and second ways?
Is there another way?

Comment: This is the wrong Forum. Maybe https://superuser.com/ or https://serverfault.com/ is the better instance for this kind of questions. But please read the "How to ask questions?" otherwise it may occure that your question will be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my view you search for optimal deployment structure, its a long way to go and find information about. Here my opinons:

1. I wouldn't recommend this version because the mix of operation system (win/linux) can cause big problems. Example, Line Breaks, Folder/File Filename.
   But the docker compose idea is the right way to setup the test, dev enviroment local.
2. is outside of git, thats not optimal, but a good solution when save everything.
3. is alright, but you done already with docker compose. Here the usage of volume can cause same problems as 1. You can use git versioning in commandline mode to develop, but I don't recommend it.

Alternative Ways

4. Use Software that able to deploy remotely to the php server, like PHPStorm, Eclipse, Winscp use local to develop the application and link it to the Apache/PHP Maschine or Container over FTP/SFTP. You work local and transfer the changed files into the running maschine or container. The Git Versioning would be done on the local maschine. You can also use mysql tools to backup the database local. So if the docker container brake you can setup it easy again.
   Make sure you save also config files of apache, php, mysql into git, that makes the resetup of docker container smart.
5. Use (Gitlab & Gitlab CI), (Bitbucket & Bamboo), (Git & Jenkins) to deploy your php changes to the servers or docker containers.
   At best read articles over continuous delivery and continuous integration.
   This option is suitable for rollout to customer or dev, beta systems.